# Resize iframe height according to resizable content

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have an iframe and I want to re-size the height according to the content which may resize if user makes certain actions.

I don't want a scroll bar so it appears as a normal page

Answer (score 0):

Use a div instead of an iFrame. Try posting some sample code so we can help you more. Generally, you cannot resize an iframe based on its content.

Comment: I can't use a div, I am using jsf 2.1, I have an upload file component which can't get its value without submitting the whole form, and my main page on the other hand can't be submitting everything is by using ajax,that is why I put the uploading file component in an ifram

Answer (score 0):

scrollHeight is the major property to retrieve the height of the IFRAME's content like this:

```
contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight
```

After the IFRAME is loaded, you can then change the height by doing the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function resizeIframe() {
      var iFrameID = document.getElementById('idIframe');
      if(iFrameID) {
           var cont =  iFrameID.contentWindow.document.body || frame.contentDocument.body
            // here you can make the height            
            iFrameID.height = cont.scrollHeight + "px";
      }   
  }
</script>
```

On the IFRAME load event, you can call this function:

But sure..iframe should not be loaded from other website

Comment: It didn't work, I a table in the iframe where the iframe height should 230px + the height of this table, my question is the onload is happening after the iframe is loaded so after the table is loaded, why I always get the height of the table "null" ??

Comment: `function resizeIframe() {
 alert("in resize");
 var iFrameID = document.getElementById('frame_name_here');
 var myheight = $('#records-view-table').height();
 if (iFrameID) {
  iFrameID.height = 300 + myheight + "px";
  alert(myheight + "fff");
 }
}`